# bootstrap - how to add a margin and make these cards display horizontally

Tags: html, layout, bootstrap-4, margin, bootstrap-cards

I have the following code and html (boostrap enabled) page which simply displays three bootstrap cards with images on the page.

I want

a) A margin from the left hand side to be included
b) The cards to display horizontally (across the screen one after the other) rather than vertically.

I have tried various things but to no avail. Could someone with a clear explanation for a beginner explain how to achieve these things.

**Full code**

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Website</h1> 
<h2>Site with multiple horizontal cards</h2>

<!-- card 1--> 
<div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
  <img src="https://cdn5.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/23/24/ladybug-insect-small-icon-animal-vector-19752324.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card 1</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- card 2--> 
<div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
  <img src="https://cdn5.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/23/24/ladybug-insect-small-icon-animal-vector-19752324.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card 1</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- card 3--> 
<div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
  <img src="https://cdn5.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/23/24/ladybug-insect-small-icon-animal-vector-19752324.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card 1</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Trinket**

https://trinket.io/html/8fcb4c4f39?runMode=autorun

**Current Display**

[image]

Update:

I have understood that I could start again and try and implement everything inside this structure

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
```

But for teaching purposes, is there an easy way to just add to what I have to achieve the result and thereby teach the principles of what is being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I modified from your posted Trinket Link

Make sure you read bootstrap documentation from official website or any tutorial about 12 grid system in bootstrap.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Website</h1> 
<h2>Site with multiple horizontal cards</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<!-- card 1--> 
<div class="col-4">
<div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
  <img src="https://cdn5.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/23/24/ladybug-insect-small-icon-animal-vector-19752324.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card 1</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- card 2--> 
<div class="col-4">
<div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
  <img src="https://cdn5.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/23/24/ladybug-insect-small-icon-animal-vector-19752324.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card 1</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- card 3--> 
<div class="col-4">
<div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
  <img src="https://cdn5.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/23/24/ladybug-insect-small-icon-animal-vector-19752324.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card 2</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Changes

[image]